# e.stopPropagation() is not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[I have a simple table](http://jsbin.com/icoxak/3/edit) :

[image]

The TR has  `<tr onclick='alert("row");'>`

And the button has :

```
$("body").on('click',".b",function (e){
  alert('button');
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

However - Although I wrote  `e.stopPropagation();` it still alerts : "row , button".

Now , I know that the event handler is attached to the `body` and the selector is checked against it ( the click start at the button and move up to the body , just like `$.live` use to do  but against `document`...).

But the checking should be for the `button` click and **not** for the `TR` click.

It seems that while i'm clicking , it propagates to the `"body"` ( because I attached event handler to it) and **while its way up to the body** it activates the click on the `TR`.

What  is going on here? How can I keep my code ( attach to body) and still have only alert of "button".

## P.s.

I know I can simply do :

```
$(".b").on('click',function (e){
  alert('button');
  e.stopPropagation();

});
```

but I want to know why my current(!) code doesnt work.

Comment: As you seem to understand that the problem is that you attach the event handler to the body, it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: @dystroy I attached the handler to the body. yes. but I also said  -  "stop propagation." so IMHO it should only alert "row". and from there - stop from going up.

Comment: delegation use propagation of event to reach delegate. Thats why an event which don't bubbles (propagate) as the onload event cannot be use with delegation.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem is that you're attaching the event handler to the `body`, even if it delegates to the `.b` element. This event handler is called only after the `tr` event handler is called, so it's too late to stop propagation.

As I suppose you want to deal with dynamically added elements and can't simply bind the event handler to the `td`, I can suggest you this :

```
$('body').on('click',"tr",function (e){
  alert('row');
});
$("body").on('click',".b",function (e){
  alert('button');
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/icoxak/5/edit)

Answer (score 9):

> ...but I want to know why my current(!) code doesnt work.

From jQuery docs, on `event.stopPropagation` with event delegation:

> Since the .live() method handles events once they have propagated to
>   the top of the document, it is not possible to stop propagation of
>   live events. Similarly, events handled by .delegate() will propagate
>   to the elements to which they are delegated; event handlers bound on
>   **any elements below it** in the DOM tree will already have been executed
>   by the time the delegated event handler is called. These handlers,
>   therefore, may prevent the delegated handler from triggering by
>   calling event.stopPropagation() or returning false.

`live` and `delegate` are now `on` so this applies.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stop the event propagation from child to parent, then you may use this code.

Let's say you have a select, button, or any other click event inside a div etc. Then Write the below code code on onclick method.

```
<button type="button" onclick="event.cancelBubble = true;" >Click Me </button>
```

or

```
<button type="button" onclick="event.cancelBubble = true; doSomething();" >Click Me </button>
```

you can replace button with any HTML input or other element.

in your specific case use

```
<tr onclick='event.cancelBubble = true; alert("row");'>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the solution worked properly in my case in Angular using [material select](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview)

```
import {Directive, HostListener} from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
    selector: "[click-stop-propagation]"
})
export class ClickStopPropagation
{
    @HostListener("click", ["$event"])
    public onClick(event: any): void
    {
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
}
```

In template use it like this

```
(click)="onClick($event)
```